# I have an requirement to convert a one XML to another XML (by XSLT) and then convert that xml to AVRO

Tags: java, xslt, transformation, avro

Now am having an XSLT to transform a XML1 to another XML2 format.

I need to transform a XML2 to AVRO format.

Now am doing like XML1--->(via XSLT)----> XML2----->AVRO

Is there any way to convert that xml directly to avro XML1---->AVRO.

Comment: Yes, the same way you are converting XML2 to AVRO. Explain how you are doing it and why are you not doing it for XML1.

Comment: Can we write a XSLT to convert a XML to AVRO??